# Getting jest error: "TypeError: Article is not a constructor"

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

I tried to figure out why the test fails for the article.service.js file with the following error:

```
TypeError: Article is not a constructor

      17 |    */
      18 |   static async saveArticle(userId, articleObj) {
    > 19 |     const newArticle = new Article();
```

But, I'm unable to find the cause of it.

I declare `Article` in `article.model.js` as a normal Mongoose model based on a normal schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const articleSchema = new Schema(
  {
    slug: { type: String },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    body: { type: String, required: true },
    tagList: [String],
    favoritesCount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
    author: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);
module.exports.Article = Article;
```

And then I load and use that in `article.service.js` as:

```js
const { Article } = require('../models/article.model');
const { currentUser } = require('../services/user.service');
const { slugify } = require('../helpers/slugify.helper');

class ArticleService {
  static async saveArticle(userId, articleObj) {
    const newArticle = new Article();

    // ...more code here...
  }
}
```

Which I trigger in my test (`article.service.test.js`) as:

```js
const slugifyHelper = require('../../../helpers/slugify.helper');
const currentUserService = require('../../../services/user.service');
const { Article } = require('../../../models/article.model');

const mockUser = {
  _id: "6368ad4347dkhs",
  email: "test@gmail.com"
};

const mockArticle = {
  title: "Sample article title",
  description: "Sample article description",
  body: "Sample article body",
  tagList: ['tag1', 'tag2']
};

// Mock the Article model
jest.mock('../../../models/article.model', () => ({
  save: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser)
}));

const slugifySpy = jest.spyOn(slugifyHelper, "slugify").mockReturnValue('mocked-slug');
const currentUserSpy = jest.spyOn(currentUserService, "currentUser").mockResolvedValue(mockUser);

describe("Unit tests for article.service.js file", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  describe("saveArticle tests", () => {
    test("If user can save an article", async () => {
      //Arrange
      const { saveArticle } = require("../../../services/article.service");

      //Act
      const result = await saveArticle(mockUser._id, mockArticle);

      //Assert
      expect(Article).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(slugifySpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(slugifySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockArticle.title);
      expect(currentUserSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(currentUserSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockUser._id);
    });
  });
});
```

I wanted to write the test suite for unit testing saveArticle function. In that test suite I tried to test both slugify and currentUser functions are called at least once and with the necessary arguments.

Comment: You forgot the file that actually matters: you're importing `Article` from `article.model` so what's in _that_ file? (reduced to only the `Article` related code of course)

Comment: added article.model.js codes.

Comment: Mock the Article model: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser) ?? why not mockArticle ?

Comment: modified to mockArticle @Mate still it is showing same error.

Comment: why you create a new Article inside saveArticle and only save if got userDetails?

Comment: if you need do that, read about mongodb-memory-server

Comment: Your `// Mock the Article model` jest code takes the actual code you wrote, throws it away, and instead mocks it as something completely different. Give https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules a (re)read so you can properly mock your `article.model` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mock the `article.model.js` module correctly. Please read the documentation [ES6 Class Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks)

e.g.

`article.model.js`:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const articleSchema = new Schema(
  {
    slug: { type: String },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

const Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);
module.exports.Article = Article;
```

`article.service.js`:

```js
const { Article } = require('./article.model');

class ArticleService {
  static async saveArticle(userId, articleObj) {
    const newArticle = new Article();
    return newArticle.save();
    // ...more code here...
  }
}

module.exports = ArticleService;
```

```js
const { Article } = require('./article.model');

const mockUser = {
  _id: '6368ad4347dkhs',
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
};

const mockArticle = {
  title: 'Sample article title',
  description: 'Sample article description',
  body: 'Sample article body',
  tagList: ['tag1', 'tag2'],
};

// Mock the Article model
jest.mock('./article.model', () => {
  return {
    Article: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      save: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser),
    })),
  };
});

describe('Unit tests for article.service.js file', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  describe('saveArticle tests', () => {
    test('If user can save an article', async () => {
      const ArticleService = require('./article.service');
      const actual = await ArticleService.saveArticle(mockUser._id, mockArticle);

      expect(Article).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(actual).toEqual(mockUser);
    });
  });
});
```